# Trying to add up rows in excel but data length is not predefined

Tags: excel, rows

So I have a sheet which is van stock per model and want to add up the number of each model available, however, the data comes in rows with **a row for the model** and then below, **each vehicle of that model in stock.** My issue is, that the number of rows for each model can change depending on how many vehicles there are of that model, that month. So I cannot simply add up the rows as they are not predefined. Is there a way to set the model types as some sort of break and then count everything in between them?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service

    Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see here to learn how to write effective questions.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: To add to that, it sounds like `SUMIF` (or possibly `COUNTIF`) would be a good starting point for you.